# Google Maps Api does not display image

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps

I have problem in implementing google maps api in asp.net. Here is my aspx code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="visual_loc.aspx.cs" Inherits="visual_loc" %>



<%--A sample project by Ghaffar khan--%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Your Data on Google Map </title>
    <%--Google API reference--%>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false
                 &amp;key=asdfg" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
                <%--Place holder to fill with javascript by server side code--%>
                <asp:Literal ID="js" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                <%--Place for google to show your MAP--%>
                <div ID="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 728px; margin-bottom:                      2px;">
                </div>
                <br />
            </asp:Panel>
        <br />
   </form>
   </body>

</html>
```

And my code behind:
 `getLocation()` is the method which gets the longitude and latitude from my database. `createDataTable()` is method which create `DataTable` from those locations.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string user_id;
        user_id = Request.Cookies["cookie"]["Login"];
        getLocation(user_id);
        BuildScript( createDataTable());

    }
    private void BuildScript(DataTable tbl)
    {
        String Locations = "";
        foreach (DataRow r in tbl.Rows)
        {
            // bypass empty rows        
            if (r["Latitude"].ToString().Trim().Length == 0)
                continue;

            string Latitude = r["Latitude"].ToString();
            string Longitude = r["Longitude"].ToString();

            // create a line of JavaScript for marker on map for this record    
            Locations += Environment.NewLine + " map.addOverlay(new GMarker(new GLatLng(" + Latitude + "," + Longitude + ")));";
        }

        // construct the final script
        js.Text = @"<script type='text/javascript'>
                            function initialize() {
                              if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
                                var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById('map_canvas'));
                                map.setCenter(new GLatLng(52.259, 21.012), 2); 
                                " + Locations + @"
                                map.setUIToDefault();
                              }
                            }
                            </script> ";
    }
```

whole operation result in displaying empty site with no content. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: It may be overkill in your situation, but I found that feeding back the locations via JSON was a much cleaner way to do it and offers good customization. I can add code if interested.

Comment: Are you running this on localhost or on a domain? If on a domain, you do have a corresponding key? https://developers.google.com/maps/signup  And the **v2 API** has been **deprecated since May 2010**.

Comment: Yes i do have valid key, and i do host it on localhost, Mike could you show me another option?Ghaffar khan

Comment: Current version is 3 which doesn't require key.

Comment: @Win if i change to `<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=3&amp;sensor=false" type="text/javascript">
    </script>` it doesnt work either..

Comment: @Win Google Maps docs still uses key: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Comment: @GrzegorzS I did something similar to: http://www.svennerberg.com/2012/03/adding-multiple-markers-to-google-maps-from-json/

Comment: @MikeSmithDev - It's true; however, it's not mandatory anymore.

Comment: @GrzegorzS - Article posted by MikeSmithDev is a good one. Please upgrade to V3, and test it with static lats & lngs. If map works, then populate json from code behind.

Comment: I'm not familar with C#, but how do you pass the result of getLocation() to createDataTable() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that i did wrong directories to my markers, so that cannot be seen on Map. Once i did enter valid directories everything works.